# variable declaration line in .sql file failing with syntax error

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have the following code in a .sql file that I run against my postgresql database:

```
INSERT INTO widget (username)
SELECT i
FROM generate_series(100, 150) AS t(i);

INSERT INTO widget2
SELECT generate_series(100, 150), 'statictext', generate_series(100, 150);
```

And I run it by doing something like "psql -U myuser -d widgets -f addwidgets.sql
But now I need to parameterize these items.  So I've created this version instead:

```
DECLARE startnum INTEGER;
DECLARE endnum INTEGER;
startnum:=100;
endnum:=150;
INSERT INTO widget (username)
SELECT i
FROM generate_series(startnum, endnum) AS t(i);

INSERT INTO widget2
SELECT generate_series(startnum, endnum), 'statictext', generate_series(startnum, endnum);
```

But it bombs because it doesn't like my startnum / endnum variables. The error message is:

```
psql:addwidgets.sql:1: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INTEGER"
LINE 1: DECLARE startnum INTEGER;
```

In searching for an answer, I found that  it could be related to the language I'm using in psql.  Right now i'm googling how to find out what scripting language my database engine is set up to understand.
But in the mean time if you have any suggestions I'd appreciate it.

**EDIT 1**

So I found this:

```
testbox:/tmp# psql -U postgres -d widgets -c "select * from pg_language;"
 lanname  | lanowner | lanispl | lanpltrusted | lanplcallfoid | laninline | lanvalidator | lanacl 
----------+----------+---------+--------------+---------------+-----------+--------------+--------
 internal |       10 | f       | f            |             0 |         0 |         2246 | 
 c        |       10 | f       | f            |             0 |         0 |         2247 | 
 sql      |       10 | f       | t            |             0 |         0 |         2248 | 
 plpgsql  |       10 | t       | t            |         11864 |     11865 |        11866 |
```

Perhaps I should specify at the top of my .sql file what language I'm using?  it would also help me to know which documentation to reference I guess.  :)

Comment: I don't think you can just write raw PL/PGSQL, you can create functions with it though.

Comment: function as in stored proc?  i don't think that's what i want to do... unless of course i have to.  this script will run as a part of a database initialization process and seed it with some required data.

Comment: you can't mix PL/pgSQL with plain SQL. You at least need to put the PL/pgSQL code into a `DO` block: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use anonymous block: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-do.html

> DO [ LANGUAGE lang_name ] code

Example:

```
DO $$
DECLARE startnum INTEGER;
        endnum INTEGER;
BEGIN
   startnum:=100;
   endnum:=150;

   INSERT INTO widget (username)
   SELECT i
   FROM generate_series(startnum, endnum) AS t(i);

   INSERT INTO widget2
   SELECT generate_series(startnum, endnum), 'statictext', 
          generate_series(startnum, endnum);
END $$
;
```